# How to secure access to my squid server?

Tags: security, squid

I need to have a secure access from the internet to my squid server.
I have:

```
auth_param basic program /usr/local/squid/libexec/ncsa_auth /usr/local/squid/etc/passwd
```

that allow 1 user to use squid from outside but:
1) how to protect squid from bruteforcing?
2) how to encrypt passwords that are send to squid from the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can protect squid against brute forcing with something like [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/). It's a fully configurable system that you can use to automatically block any user/ip/etc after attempting a couple of logins on one of your services.
2. Use a VPN/SSH tunnel to connect to squid. With HTTP everything will not be encrypted by default, so if you want it secure, tunnel it via an encrypted protocol.